# Unable to search inside the vendor/ directory in atom

Tags: atom-editor

I am working on a Laravel project, but when I try to use the "project search" or "fuzzy open" features, none of the files in the `vendor/` directory are being found.

I tried changing the list of 'Ignored Files' to just `.git`, didn't work.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Have you tried changing the setting for *Settings > Core Settings > Exclude VCS Ignored Paths*? This is checked by default, and the fuzzy finder will not show files that are ignored.

More info here: https://discuss.atom.io/t/project-search-does-not-index-files-in-gitignore/2804

Here's a screenshot showing the box to uncheck:

[image: Atom Core Settings]

Comment: Yes, I changed the paths and set it to just `.git`, but this did not work.

Comment: @adityamenon I think you misunderstood. You have to uncheck the box. I just tried it and search started working in vendor. Changing the path or the .gitignore file doesn't work. Seems to be a bug, but for now unchecking the box should work.